# Which is more faster A). Data load from informatica power exchange to snowflake or B). Data load from AWS S3 to Snowflake

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, informatica-powercenter

Please suggesting the best approach to load data to the snowflake , I'm currently confused between tow approaches

A). Load the Data first from Informatica Power centre to s3 and then to snowflake

B). Load the data directly from Informatica to snowflake and parallelly from Informatica to s3.

My end goal is to have data in both S3 and snowflake, just confused about which approach to follow.

And I need to have incremental data in snowflake not just data append.

Comment: Logical  if we should first load in s3 and then snowflake should be better and faster approach.

Comment: Thanks Sandeep , So what could be the best cost-efficient method to load incremental data to snowflake from s3 , heard of snowpipe but it only handles data append not upsert scenario? Any suggestions on this.

Comment: To be more cost effective remove the data from S3 but that is very less ..

Answer (score 0):

I think option A if data volume is huge, Informatica mapping, logic is complex and takes a lot of time to cache/process/load all data.
But if you are processing less data and informatica mapping isn't complex and doesn't have active transformations(AGG, SRT, JNR etc.), Informatica server is very powerful and takes less time then you can opt for B. Also note parallelism in option B is huge +.
My recommendation would be test out both options since both has their pros,cons.